# Many corresponding authors in elsarticle class

Tags: elsarticle

I need to put 3 corresponding authors using the elsarticle class. The problem I found is that there is not '***' as superscript of the third author name.

```
\author{name1\corref{firstcorr}\fnref{firstfoot}}
\cortext[firstcorr]{mailaddress1}

\author{name2\corref{secondcorr}\fnref{secondfoot}}
\cortext[secondcorr]{mailaddress2}

\author{name3\corref{thirdcorr}\fnref{thirdfoot}}
\cortext[thirdcorr]{mailaddress3}

\fntext[firstfoot]{Affiliation1}
\fntext[secondfoot]{Affiliation2}
\fntext[thirdfoot]{Affiliation3}
```

Example in which *** do not appear in the third author:

[image]

The email is shown without asterisks

[image]

How to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: In my understanding, there should only ever be *at most one* corresponding author. Please clarify what you're trying to achieve by listing three corresponding authors. Your code doesn't make effective use of the `\corref`/`\cortext` machinery. If you simply mean to use it to state mailing addresses, you shouln't be using `\corref`/`\cortext` in the first place.

Comment: @Mico , as many institutions give some additional points for being corresponding author, it is not extraneous to have more than one correspondig author

Comment: In that case, you should contact the powers-that-be at Elsevier and communicate to them a feature request, viz., the ability to designate as many of the authors as "corresponding authors" as one wishes while using the `elsarticle` LaTeX document class. That's a feature request, and feature requests are off-topic for this site.

Comment: And if the institution you're working for is sufficiently simple-minded and gullible to take the presence of the string "Corresponding Author" on the title page of a journal article as evidence that the author is indeed a "corresponding author", there's nothing to stop your (or anyone else...) from including the string "Corresponding Author" in the argument of `\fntext`, is there?

Comment: @Mico , thank you for reply. Elsevier class documentation does not specify that limitation. Up to 2 correspondig authors works fine. Nevertheless, I do not ask for a feature request of the official Elsevier class. I ask for a TeX/LaTeX code that solve an specific LaTeX issue which can be summarized as how to get the asterisks in the right positions. I did so, but asterisk does not appear rightly.

Comment: Asking to lift the limit on the number of corresponding authors (this limit appears to be 2) that can be identified visually via `\corref` and `\cortext`directives *is* a feature request.

Comment: @Mico , I should edit the question for avoiding confusion. I want the asterisks no matter the command used. I used those directives because I think than they are the usual way to show the correspondig authors. By the way, I look more for a hack and I do not wish that Elsevier changes its class.

Comment: @Mico could you added yout suggestion of used \fntext into your answer, so I can finally accept it. I do not find it perfect but I think is good enough.

Comment: I'll be happy to add a couple of sentences to my answer to cover the `\fntext` idea. A separate comment: While it's presumably possible to hack the `elsarticle` document class ot allow for more than two `\corref` and `\cortext`, it's actually a really bad idea to do so. If and when you submit your paper to an Elsevier journal, they will use their stock document class, *not* your hacked version. Hence, you'll be right back where you started, i.e., you can't have more than two "official" corresponding authors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(edited to discuss the use of `\fntext` directives to provide additional information about an author, such as that he/she is to be taken to be a "corresponding author")

You wrote,

> I need to put 3 corresponding authors using the `elsarticle` class.

If all you need to do is list the authors' correspondence addresses, you should *definitely not* be using the `\corref`/`\cortext` machinery to provide address-related information. Instead, use `\address` directives to state the authors' correspondence addresses.

A general comment: It usually makes little sense to list more than 1 author as "corresponding" author. The whole point of designating an author as the "corresponding author" is to channel inquiries, comments, suggestions, criticisms, and all other communications to a single person. If *all* authors of a journal article are in a position to react to communications about their journal article, there's simply no need to provide footnotes to point out that all authors are, in fact, qualified to receive communications related to the article.

The `elsarticle` document class actually allows one to specify 1 or 2 authors to be "corresponding" authors via `\corref` and `\cortext` directives. If, for whatever reason, you need to designate more than 2 authors as "corresponding" authors, I would recommend that you use `\fnref` and `\fntext` machinery to do so (and, conversely, not use the `\corref`/`\cortext` machinery).

---

Given the information you provided in your code fragment, it's probably a very good idea to employ `\address` directives to state the authors' correspondence addresses. If you need to provide email addresses as well, provide `\ead` directives immediately after the corresponding `\author{...}` directives.

In the following screenshot, I've highlighted the various footnote-type markers. Note that only 1 author is designated as the "corresponding" author.

[image]

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\title{A title}

\author[1]{Name1\fnref{firstfoot}}
\author[2]{Name2\corref{aaa}\fnref{secondfoot}}
\author[3]{Name3\fnref{thirdfoot}}

\cortext[aaa]{Corresponding Author}
\address[1]{Mailing Address 1}
\address[2]{Mailing Address 2}
\address[3]{Mailing Address 3}
\fntext[firstfoot]{Affiliation1}
\fntext[secondfoot]{Affiliation2}
\fntext[thirdfoot]{Affiliation3}

\date{\today}
\setlength\textheight{5cm}  % just for this example

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```